# parse unrecognized timestamp format

Tags: c#

How do I get the time-stamp to look like this "2013-06-07T00:04:48Z"? I can't even decode it to get what time it is, what standard does it supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, natively supported by `DateTime`. It is recommended format for XML date fields, also have very nice property of being sortable with string comparison.

Sample:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-07T00:04:48Z");
```

Note that `Z` denotes UTC time-zone and parsed value will be converted to your local timezone.

To convert `DateTime` to that format use ["u"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalSortable) or ["O"/"o"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Sample:

```
 var isoDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("u"); // 2013-07-19 20:15:10Z
```

Note that `T` is optional in the format, "O" option gives you string with local timezone instead of UTC.

Comment: How can I export datetime as ISO8601?

Comment: @user2601259 "O"/"o"/"u" format strings - added to the answer.